# Unable to get Highcharts working

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get this Highchart demo chart to work on my local web server: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but it won't load in any browser at all.

This is the code I placed in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see jQuery in your page, try adding:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Highcharts requires either jQuery, MooTools or Prototype](http://docs.highcharts.com/#installation).

Comment: And this should be placed before including Highcharts.